# react-hook-form Controller issues

Tags: reactjs, controller, react-hooks, material-ui, react-hook-form

Hi im trying to do one form with react-hook-form and material-ui. I don't want to write Controller every time for all TextFields. Because of that i declare it in another file and call it in my form but its not working i didn't understand why, because in some videos that i watched is working. What is the problem and how i can fix it ?

**Form Field**

```
import React from 'react'
import { TextField, Grid } from '@material-ui/core'
import { useForm, Controller, useFormContext  } from 'react-hook-form'

const FormField = ({name, label}) => {
const { control } = useForm()

return (
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} >
        <Controller 
            render = {({field}) => 
            <TextField 
                {...field}        
                label={label} required
            />}
            name={name}
            control = {control}
            defaultValue=""
        />
    </Grid>
)
}


export default FormField
```

**Adress Form**

```
import React from 'react'
import { InputLabel, Select, MenuItem, Button, Grid, Typography, TextField } from '@material-ui/core'
import { useForm, FormProvider, Controller } from 'react-hook-form'
import FormField from './FormField'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const AdressForm = ({next}) => {
const {handleSubmit, control} = useForm()
return (
    <>
        <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>Shipping Address </Typography>
        
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data) )}>
                <Grid container spacing={3}>
                    <FormField name='firstName' label='First Name' required='required'/>
                    <FormField name='lastName' label='Last Name' />
                    <FormField name='email' label='Email' />
                    <FormField name='phoneNumber' label='Phone Number' />
                </Grid>
                <br/>
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                     <Button component={Link} to="/cart" variant="outlined">Back to Cart</Button>
                     <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">Next</Button>
                </div>
            </form>
        
    </>
)
}

export default AdressForm
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use one `useForm` hook for each form, in your code, you call `useForm` in every `Field` components, creating multiple independent form states, which leads to unexpected result.

What you need to do is to call `useForm` in the parent element and pass the dependencies (`register`, `formState`, `error`...) down the child components, so your form can have one unified state. If you have a deeply nested components, you can use [`useFormContext`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext) to pass the form context to the nested children easily:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useForm, FormProvider, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const methods = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods} > // pass all methods into the context
      <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <NestedInput />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
}

function NestedInput() {
  const { register } = useFormContext(); // retrieve all hook methods
  return <input {...register("test")} />;
}
```